# How to split dataframe and be able to work with sub-dataframes in R

Tags: r, split

here is the problem. I have a dataframe, suppose like this:

```
sp    rd  pH abund area point
dog  uniq 4.5     5    1     a
dog  uniq 4.2     5    1     a
dog   for 6.1     3    1     a
cat  uniq 7.0     8    1     a
cat  uniq 4.9     5    1     a
cat mains 3.1     9    1     b
cat mains 6.5     1    1     b
cat mains 6.5     3    1     b
dog   for  NA     2    2     a
bird   mac 5.0    3    2     a
bird   mac 4.1    5    2     a
bird   mac 5.1   NA    2     a
rabb  lol 5.0     8    2     b
rabb  lol 4.2     5    2     b
rabb  lol 6.0     2    2     b
rabb  lol 2.8     3    2     b
```

and id like to split this dataframe in several dataframes by unique combinations of `area` and `point` (1a, 1b, 2a, 2b) and want still be able to work with them separatelly. For example i want to find out mean abund in each group. I tried to use `split` function but the issue is, that each group has only name for example 1.a and i cant order R to do anything inside this dataframe.

Thx for answers.

Comment: `library(data.table); setDT(DF)[, {DO STUFF HERE}, by=.(area,point)]` Introductory material for this library can be found here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: `transform(DF, mean_abund = ave(abund, area, point))` .  or perhaps `aggregate(abund ~ area + point, DF, mean)` depending on what you want.

Comment: why not `sprintf("%i%s", df$area, df$point)` into a new column and then `group_by` copiously?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your problem correctly here's my attempt below:

```
sp <-
c("dog","dog","dog","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","dog","bird","bird",
"bird","rabb","rabb","rabb","rabb")

rd <- 
c("uniq","uniq","for","uniq","uniq","mains","mains","mains",
"for","mac","mac","mac","lol","lol","lol","lol")

pH <- 
c(4.5,4.2,6.1,7.0,4.9,3.1,6.5,6.5,NA,5.0,4.1,5.1,5.0,4.2,6.0,2.8)

abund <- 
c(5,5,3,8,5,9,1,3,2,3,5,NA,8,5,2,3)

area <- 
c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)

point <- 
c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b")

df <- data.frame(sp,rd,pH,abund,area,point)

cols <-c("area","point")

df$group <- apply(df[,cols],1,paste,collapse="")
df$group <- as.factor(df$group)
str(df$group)
sapply(split(df$abund,df$group),mean,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Let me know

```
  1a       1b       2a       2b 
5.200000 4.333333 3.333333 4.500000
```

Here's an alternative if someone does want to split the dataframe. Here's how the data frame looks like now based on this step

```
df$group <- apply(df[,cols],1,paste,collapse="")
df
     sp    rd  pH abund area point group
1   dog  uniq 4.5     5    1     a    1a
2   dog  uniq 4.2     5    1     a    1a
3   dog   for 6.1     3    1     a    1a
4   cat  uniq 7.0     8    1     a    1a
5   cat  uniq 4.9     5    1     a    1a
6   cat mains 3.1     9    1     b    1b
7   cat mains 6.5     1    1     b    1b
8   cat mains 6.5     3    1     b    1b
9   dog   for  NA     2    2     a    2a
10 bird   mac 5.0     3    2     a    2a
11 bird   mac 4.1     5    2     a    2a
12 bird   mac 5.1    NA    2     a    2a
13 rabb   lol 5.0     8    2     b    2b
14 rabb   lol 4.2     5    2     b    2b
15 rabb   lol 6.0     2    2     b    2b
16 rabb   lol 2.8     3    2     b    2b
```

Now if you want to split by group:

```
df1a    <- df[grepl("1a",df$group),]

df1a 

   sp   rd  pH abund area point group
1 dog uniq 4.5     5    1     a    1a
2 dog uniq 4.2     5    1     a    1a
3 dog  for 6.1     3    1     a    1a
4 cat uniq 7.0     8    1     a    1a
5 cat uniq 4.9     5    1     a    1a
```

Comment: Thx a lot but this dont solve my problem. I need to split my dataframe to dataframes, that is possible to work with. Solving mean problem teaches me to solve this and only this little problem. But thank you very much again.

Comment: Hmmmm ok I can revise it, I thought you meant more of Split - Apply - Combine paradigm. Let me clarify, you want to create several data frames based on a column combination and then calculate their mean? What is the purpose of subseting if the answer provided addresses your issue without having to create extra objects?

Comment: I edited the code however, I don't personally see a point of splitting the df into newdf and calculating mean when you can just do it with sapply ( )

Answer (score 0):

Try using "group_by". I'm not sure the exact data you'd want, but if you wanted the average pH by each combination of area and point, you can do:

You'll obviously have to handle your NA values, but this will sort things out by unique group combinations.

```
df.grp <- group_by(df, area, point) %>%
summarize(meanpH = mean(pH))
```